# Proportional null vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vectors

the past few days I've been studying special relativity and was just now making some exercices on it. One exercice was the following:

> Let $U$ and $V$ be two null vector is a $d$-dimensional Minkowski space. Proof that if $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, that $U$ and $V$ are proportional.

The only thing I could find was that $U-V$ is also a null vector but I don't know if that is enough to deduce that $U$ and $V$ are proportional to one another. Does anyone have a tip? Any help would be greatly appreciated :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the vectors be $(x^0,{\bf x})$ and $(y^0,{\bf y})$. As we are only interested in propertionalilty, we can, without loss of generality,  scale the vectors so that $x^0=y^0=1$. Then, both being null means that $1- |{\bf x}|^2=1-  |{\bf y}|^2=0$, so the space parts of the rescaled vectors are  unit vectors. Being Lorentz-metric orthogonal means $1-{\bf x}\cdot {\bf  y}=0$ so ${\bf x}\cdot {\bf  y}=1$. Two unit vectors with inner propduct unity, must be the same vector.  Before rescaling they  were therefore proportional.

This is a neat problem!

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I understand it now :))